# CSS3 Calc() returning negative value

Tags: css

I'm using the `calc()` functionality in CSS3. I have a header that is `123px` tall. So for my class I'm placing:

```
.overlay { height: calc(100% - 123px) }
```

This keeps getting evaluated as `-23px`.

Any thoughts? Is there a better way to represent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well my guess is that your parent(s) are not having 100% height.

Eg `html, body { height: 100%; }` and perhaps other children that may be parents of the "overlay" (if any).

I am not sure tho, nor that I had any experience with negative value, just a guess.

Other than that, I don't see why it would return negative value.

---

Here's example of `html` and `body` being parents of that `.overlay`.

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLden/8m1zjvaj/)

And here's example of `html`, `body` and `.another-parent` being parents of that `.overlay`.

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLden/thx3r8Lf/)

Keep in mind that I used `position: relative` on `.overlay` in both examples as assumption. Although overlays are mostlikely suppoused to be `absolute` or `fixed` - hence they won't depend on parent(s) height.

Answer (score 0):

of course it will go to minus, cuz 100% is unpredictable when it's parent element is also has no fixed parameters. try to set min-height param to prevent getting height down than 0

```
 .overlay: { 
  height:calc(100% - 123px); 
  min-height: 10px; 
}
```

also You can make it fixed position if You want to widen it to full screen, so then it will get 100% of browser area.